# How to partition by fixed number of rows for same category in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, partition, row-number

I want to partition my dataset into rows of 4 per category.

For example, I want to partition the following df into 4 rows each for same category 'a'

```
df:
category, number
a, 1  
a, 2  
a, 3  
a, 4 
-------------- <-- partition
a, 2  
a, 3
a, 4
a, 5
```

I then want to return the first value for each partition in aa new column.

```
df:
category, number, batch
a, 1, 1
a, 2, 1  
a, 3, 1  
a, 4, 1 
a, 2, 2  
a, 3, 2
a, 4, 2
a, 5, 2
```

I tried doing `row_number() over (partition by category, number)` but that return `batch=1` for `number=5` as it is the first instance.

Solution:

```
row_number() over(partition by category)-1)/4+1 as batch
```

Comment: `partiton by category` only and divide result by 4.

Comment: Is it acceptable grouping any 4 row as one category? other case what is your ordering key?

Comment: @sam92 , add your solution as the answer